# What altitudes did the first astronauts reach?

Tags: history, spaceflight-firsts, altitude

Including the suborbital flight of Alan Shepard, what altitudes did the first men in space reach? I am looking for a list of maybe the first 5-10 people who reached orbit, but also the first suborbital flights around that period.

An infographic gets bonus points!

Comment: What about X-15 flights?  They got 'astronaut' wings for those flights.

Comment: I considered asking about those flights as well, but wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Stu "Fix your little problem and light this candle" -Alan B. Shepard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really depends on your definition of astronaut. The Google definition is:

```
a person who is trained to travel in a spacecraft.
```

I'd suggest that the first person ever *trained* to travel in a spacecraft never actually flew. Again this depends on your definition of training though I suppose.

However I fear this isn't the answer you're looking for. If you're definition is the first man into space then we're talking about Yuri Gagarin, at 324.9 km apogee.

Interestingly if you type "yuri gagarin altitude" into Google it tells you his height - either that or he flew a very low spacecraft at some point. Put together the two facts from this answer and what do you have? [Nonsense!](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vostok%201%20apogee/%20yuri%20gagarin%20height). :)

Edit:
The following apogee altitudes are in kilometres. They are ordered by launch date.

```
Vostok 1    324.9       (Gagarin)
Mercury 3   187.5       (Shepard, suborbital)
Mercury 4   190.31      (Grissom, suborbital)
Vostok  2   244         (Titov)
Mercury 6   265         (Glenn)
Mercury 7   260         (Carpenter)
Vostok  3   218         (Nikolayev)
Vostok  4   211         (Popovich)
Mercury 8   283         (Schirra)
Mercury 9   267         (Cooper)
```

Enjoy!

Comment: haha yup, i also tried "yuri gagarin altitude". Thanks. I am looking for a list of the first n-number of men in space, maybe 5-10. Just curious how high those earlier developments got them.

Comment: stand 206,000 Yuri's on top of each other and the last one will reach his apogee.

Comment: Ha! That's either a novel way to reach space, or a terrible excuse to clone Yuri. I've added the data I believe you're looking for.

Comment: yup, that's perfect! thanks. interesting how no one reached Yuri's apogee for a long time..

Comment: @Stu 349KM is 200 miles, isn't that below the ISS altitude?

Comment: @geoffc:  it is not surprising that these missions are below ISS altitude.  They were all short duration-the longest Mercury mission was less than 2 days, Vostok 2 was about 25 hours.  You don't need a higher altitude to stay aloft that long, and it reduces the rocket payload to go higher.  ISS is designed to stay aloft for decades, so needs to be higher to reduce the drag and therefore the reboost requirements.

Comment: @RossMillikan No dispute. I was responding to Stu's comment that no one reached Yuri's apogee for a long time.  (I read into that, long as even till this day sort of thing).

Comment: @geoffc i just meant over that handful of early flights, but obviously i didn't clarify!

Comment: Yuri only got to 5'2" altitude? Oh man! All those wasted nights in April to celebrate Yuri's Night for nought.

Comment: IIRC there was a specific purpose behind the low altitude of the early Soviet flights: the Vostoks/Voskhods were supplied to allow astronaut survival for two weeks, which was the time for the capsule to deorbit due to natural orbit decay - in case deorbiting engines fail.

Comment: @DavidHammen - c'mon nobody ever reached an orbit this low again!

Comment: Russian uses the same word for height and altitude so maybe Google is thrown off by bad translation?

Comment: @ventsyv - No, google is thrown off by it's own machine (non)intelligence. It interprets "altitude" as "height," and then infers that since Yuri Gregarin was a person, the person issuing the query "yuri gregarin altitude" was intending to ask "how tall was Yuri Gregarin?" Yuri Gregarin was rather short, 5 feet and 2 inches tall, or 5'2" for short (pun not intended).

Comment: @DavidHammen is that truly a flaw in Google's synonym mapping or is it a flaw with the English language? I would guess that Yuri Gregarin altitude does mean height by every rule of grammar and syntax - so I guess the fault is with me! :)

Comment: @ThePlanMan - While google has come a long way from its early days, that a search for "yuri gagarin altitude" yields (in a nice box!) 5' 2" is a shining example of John Searle's Chinese room argument. If on the other hand you search for "yuri gagarin maximum altitude", google does the right thing.

Comment: @DavidHammen it seems to me that google being wrong about the process doesn't make it a good example of the Chinese room argument, in fact I've had conversations with people learning English and these types of misinterpretation are quiet common. If anything a mistake like this suggests cognition and understanding (albeit limited understanding). Of course I'm not suggesting google has hard AI, but if I were the Chinesse speaker posting questions through the door this might convince me that I was speaking to a human not a machine (or at least wouldn't suggest it was a machine).